# Protractor - Using IEDriverServer_Win32

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, automated-tests

I set up protractor and it works fine on chrome and `IE` except for the `SendKeys` method in `IE`.

I read I should use the 32 bit driver to fix that.
I installed the required driver using `webdriver-manager update --ie32` command and I can see it in the `..\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium` folder as it should.

Problem is the webdriver-manager keeps looking for the 64 bit version and I keep getting

> "08:13:11.603 WARN - Exception: The driver executable does not exist:
>   C:\Users\emuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pr
>   otractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1.exe"

any ideas?

Comment: Please place the IEDriverServer.exe in the bin>debug folder. i.e., in the same folder where your project exe is present

Comment: Try renaming your IEDriverServer.exe with IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1.exe

Comment: thanks @SudharsanSelvaraj that worked :) embarrassed i didn't think about it myself

make sure to write a comment and i'll mark it as correct